# Tomcat log: What's the difference between %D and %F?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, logging, request

I am using Tomcat log to log the access info. And the definitions of `%D` and `%F` in official doc are:

- `%D` - Time taken to process the request, in millis
- `%F` - Time taken to commit the response, in millis

I am confused by these two definitions. Does the time of `%F` include the time of `%D`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`%D` includes `%F` plus any network time

There is a bit more information in the API Doc
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html

> `AccessLogValve.ElapsedTimeElement` write time taken to process the
> request - %D, %T
>
> `AccessLogValve.FirstByteTimeElement` write time until first byte is
> written (commit time) in millis - `%F`

In the [Bugzilla 55102 entry for `%F`](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55102) it says:

> Tomcat's `AccessLogValve` is able to report the time taken to send an
> entire request using `%D`. This is the total processing time and may be
> affected by network conditions. It is sometimes useful to be able to
> record the time taken by the server to prepare the response and send
> the first content to the client.
>
> Attached is a patch that records the time the response is committed
> and then allows that to be reported in the access log using a `%F`
> pattern (which is the same as used by the `mod-log-firstbyte` module for
> HTTPD).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the unit for `%D` in tomcat 8 is millisecond, while in tomcat 10 it's microsecond...

So `%{ms}T` in tomcat 10 could be used as a equivalence for `%D` in tomcat 8.

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/valve.html