# My nginx takes a long time to process. How can I further solve the problem($upstream_header_time)

Tags: java, nginx, tomcat

1、environment

OS version and kernel: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009   3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64

nginx version: nginx-1.14.2 (Community nginx)

upstream server(tomcat) version: apache tomcat 8.0.53

JDK version: Oracle jdk1.8.0_144

nginx enable keepalive (with client and upstream server)；

HTTP Procotol: HTTP/1.1

2、nginx access log format and  tomcat access log patten:

(1) nginx access log format

```
'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_iso8601] '
' "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent $bytes_sent '
' $request_trace_id '
' ["$upstream_addr" "$upstream_status" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_response_length" "$upstream_cache_status" '
' "$upstream_response_time" "$upstream_connect_time" "$upstream_header_time"] '
' "$request_time" "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$ssl_protocol"';
```

self-defined variable: $request_trace_id:

```
#trace.setting
set $request_trace_id $http_x_request_id;
if ( $request_trace_id = '' ) {
    set $request_trace_id $pid-$connection-$bytes_sent-$msec;
}
```

(2) tomcat access log pattern:

```
"[%{Y-M-d H:m:s.S+z}t] real_ip:%{X-Real-IP}i remote:%h requestid:%{X-Request-ID}i first_line:&quot;%r&quot; status:%s bytes:%b cost:%Dms commit_time:%Fms Agent:&quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; %{Connection}i %{Connection}o %{Keep-Alive}i %{Keep-Alive}o"
```

3、Problematic logging contents

(1) nginx logs

```
192.168.26.73 - cgpadmin [2021-09-09T09:58:23+08:00]  "POST /cgp2-oauth/oauth/check_token HTTP/1.1" 200 12983 13364  6462-1025729-0-1631152697.976  ["127.0.0.1:8801" "200" "13353" "12991" "-"  "5.026" "0.000" "5.026"]  "5.026" "-" "Java/1.8.0_144" "-" "-"
1631152697.976 timestamp:
2021-09-09 09:58:17.976
```

(2) tomcat logs

```
[2021-9-9 9:58:17.993+CST] real_ip:192.168.26.73 remote:127.0.0.1 requestid:6462-1025729-0-1631152697.976 first_line:"POST /cgp2-oauth/oauth/check_token HTTP/1.1" status:200 bytes:12991 cost:17ms commit_time:16ms Agent:"Java/1.8.0_144" - - - -
```

4、My judgment and analysis

Several times of nginx:

```
- variables
$request_time    5.026 seconds
$upstream_response_time   5.026 seconds
$upstream_header_time     0.000 seconds
$upstream_connect_time    5.026 seconds


- logs timestamp
nginx deal with proxy_pass :  2021-09-09 09:58:17.976
The moment when nginx processing is completed: 2021-09-09T09:58:23

Several times of tomcat:
- attributes
%D 17 millisecond
%F 16 millisecond

- logs timestamp
The moment when tomcat processing is completed: 2021-9-9 9:58:17.993
```

Analyze the problem stage:

The total processing time of nginx ($request_time) is because the processing time of upstream ($upstream_response_time);

In upstream processing, nginx first prepares the contents of the request message,
and then establishes a connection with Tomcat.
The connection time is very short (the log I excerpted here is 0. It may be because the connection is maintained.
I have seen other connections, which are also very short (there are cases where it is not 0),
so $upstream_header_Time can be basically confirmed
After nginx connects with tomcat, "start sending request message to Tomcat", "Tomcat receiving" (I understand that there may be a queue,
Tomcat receiving), "Tomcat processing" and "Tomcat returning" "Response message", "nginx receives the first byte of the response message header",
which takes a long time. Start to analyze the problem of which section

The recording time of nginx completion time is 9:58:23 (I don't know milliseconds here, because I use the default variable),
while the total time consumption of upstream is 5.026 seconds.
The time when tomcat returns the message is 9:58:17.993,Subtracting 5.026 seconds from 9:58:23 is about 9:58:18, which is similar to the time
when Tomcat returns the message, indicating that there is a difference between nginx and the client
The time-consuming is not long. We can basically confirm that the time when nginx establishes a connection to Tomcat is about 9:58:18.
We happen to have a $request_trace_ID, This is when nginx starts processing the reverse proxy,  it is 2021-09-09 09:58:17.976,
which can basically confirm our conjecture.
The time of Tomcat reverse message is 9:58:17.993,It subtracts the internal processing time of Tomcat (% d 17 ms),
and obtains that the time when Tomcat starts processing requests is 9:58:17.976, which is the same as our $request_trace_id 09:58:17.976
It is basically the same, indicating that nginx starts sending request messages to tomcat, and the processing time of sorting threads
from the pool is basically No.
Therefore, the processing time 5 of upstream is after Tomcat prepares the response message,
Send the response message to nginx.
The time when nginx receives the first byte of the response message header (127.0.0.1) basically has no network problems,
and the monitoring does not see it.
Is there a queue in nginx? Isn't upstream an event callback based on epoll
The system here sometimes has pre problems and sometimes post problems (in this case, post problems).
Please give me some ideas to promote this problem. Thank you!

5、reference

https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-logging-for-application-performance-monitoring/

[Tomcat log: what's the difference between %D and %F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685694/tomcat-log-whats-the-difference-between-d-and-f)

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html

https://juejin.cn/post/6844903887757901832

https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/article/1778734

Comment: #1 Use apache, haproxy or another version of nginx to validate some rare bug or misconfiguration in your current nginx? #2 Does your app (deployed on tomcat) needs some special configurations? or is just a classic web / api / microservice ?